# SF2 - Proper place to store CSS and related images

Tags: css, symfony, assets

Right now I have my CSS in:
`/web/css/` directory.
It's also what Symfony Demo app uses.

Where should I store additional images used by CSS? 
Simply in `/web/images/` or maybe in my `src/AppBundle/something`?

I notice some other files in `/web/bundles/name/` - should I move everything there?

I'm sorry it may look like a simple and stupid question, but it's confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place it wherever you want it and wherever it can be loaded by the browser.

Normally, `web/` would be your server root. This means that only things in the `web/` directory can be accessed by the browser.

How you name the directories, subdirectories, files, etc. is all up to you. Make a nice choice :)

Comment: I'm not sure it doesn't make any difference... 

http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html suggests to use `AppBundle/Resources` but then I need some method of copying files from `Resources` to `/web`, correct? 

Also, what if I compile a couple of .css files into one and they remain publicly visible in `/web/css`?

Comment: Current Official Symfony Best Practices clearly states NOT to store assets inside a bundle but in `/web` unless using Assetic.